# Stream the JSON Results of Curl into Data Parameter of Curl

Tags: json, bash, curl, input, stream

I'm trying to stream the JSON output from one curl into the data parameter of another curl. Possible?

**Step 1:** For example the curl that outputs the JSON is:

```
curl -sG api.com/test -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" | jq '.[] | select(.query|test("latency")) | @json'
```

Returning:

```
"{\"query\":\"origin == 'router' and name == 'latency'\",\"threshold\":{\"critical\":65000,\"warning\":55000,\"type\":\"UPPER\"}}"
```

**Step 2:** If I use the output of the first curl in the second curl I have a successful response:

```
curl -v "api.com/test" --data "{\"query\":\"origin == 'router' and name == 'latency'\",\"threshold\":{\"critical\":20000,\"warning\":15000,\"type\":\"UPPER\"}}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Successful response:

```
{
  "query" : "origin == 'router' and name == 'latency'",
  "threshold" : {
    "critical" : 20000.0,
    "type" : "UPPER",
    "warning" : 15000.0
  }
}
```

**Step 1 and 2 Combined:** I'm trying to combine both steps into one like so:

```
curl -sG hapi.com/test -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" | jq '.[] | select(.query|test("latency")) | @json' | curl -d @- -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "api.com/test"
```

But keep getting a bad request:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1553950852034,
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message" : "Bad Request",
  "path" : "/test"
}
```

Possible?

Comment: INSTANCE_REGION=$(curl -sG api.com/test -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" | jq '.[] | select(.query|test("latency")) | @json') |  curl -v "api.com/test" --data $INSTANCE_REGION -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Comment: Returns a `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: Must be ur auth header.

Comment: Perhaps. I did make sure that the token is valid btw.

Comment: Have you tried without piping the output of the `select` filter to `@json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes you see in your output from the first command are *literal* quotes, added by `@json`. They differ from the quotes you use in the second example, which are just *syntactic* quotes to protect the contents from shell expansion.

When piping directly from the first `curl` to the second, the syntactic quotes aren't necessary, since the shell never sees the data. You need to remove the `@json` filter which is wrapping your response in quotes.

```
auth="Authorization: Bearer ${token}"
curl -sG hapi.com/test -H "$auth" |
  jq '.[] | select(.query|test("latency"))' |
  curl -d @- -H "$auth" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "api.com/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
curl -v "api.com/test" --data "`curl -v -sG api.com/test -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" | jq '.[] | select(.query|test("latency")) | @json'`"
```

Comment: Tried this a still got a 400 response.

Comment: Can you post the actal output with the '-v' flag for the above?

Comment: *   Trying IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.com/test (IP) port 80 (#0)
> POST /v1/alert-configurations HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <redacted>
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 136
>
* upload completely sent off: 136 out of 136 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2019 14:22:58 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache

Comment: < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Vcap-Request-Id: <redacted>
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Length: 232
<
{
  "timestamp" : 1553955778371,
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message" : "Bad Request",
  "path" : "/test"
* Connection #0 to host api.com left intact
}